# Display PDF file stored in google drive to WebView

Tags: android, pdf, webview

My app looks like:
[My app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7zgu.png)

and this is my code for webview:

```
private String myPdfUrl = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rquwQNdXeds39Rlb32isX3bjYghHitCV";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(myPdfUrl);
            return true;
        }
    }
    );
    webView.loadUrl(myPdfUrl);

}
```

My problem is: when I run in Genymotion with API 19,21, It works. But in API 25, The WebView show only white screen.

[My app screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEhKL.png)

Comment: WebViews cannot display pdf files.

Comment: I don't know how it work with api 19. But the api 25 doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn

```
private String myPdfUrl = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rquwQNdXeds39Rlb32isX3bjYghHitCV";
```

into

```
private String myPdfUrl = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rquwQNdXeds39Rlb32isX3bjYghHitCV/view";
```

Since Google is redirecting you to another URL.

**Edit:**

add `@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")` above your `onCreate()`

```
//...
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//...
```

You have to suppress that Javascript security issue:)

Comment: Thank you! But I tried both String. It work with api 19, but api 25 doesn't.